# Unknown column 'titletext' in 'field list'

Tags: php

I'm having the error listed above when I try to update my database through php. The error seems to be coming from the titletext which is a column in my database. The images seem to update ok but I'm having problem with the text.Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');

$updateid= $_POST['updaterow'];

$updatetitletext= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['newtitletext']));
$updatemaintext= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['newmaintext']));

$updateslidetitle1= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['newslidetitle1']));
$updateslidetitle2= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['newslidetitle2']));
$updateslidetitle3= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['newslidetitle3']));

$updateslidetext1= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['newslidetext1']));
$updateslidetext2= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['newslidetext2']));
$updateslidetext3= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['newslidetext3']));

$updateslide1 = $_FILES['updateslide1']['name'];
$updateslide1temp = $_FILES['updateslide1']['tmp_name'];
$updateslide1type = $_FILES['updateslide1']['type'];
$updateslide1size = $_FILES['updateslide1']['size'];

$updateslide2 = $_FILES['updateslide2']['name'];
$updateslide2temp = $_FILES['updateslide2']['tmp_name'];
$updateslide2type = $_FILES['updateslide2']['type'];
$updateslide2size = $_FILES['updateslide2']['size'];

$updateslide3 = $_FILES['updateslide3']['name'];
$updateslide3temp = $_FILES['updateslide3']['tmp_name'];
$updateslide3type = $_FILES['updateslide3']['type'];
$updateslide3size = $_FILES['updateslide3']['size'];


if (!empty($updateslide1)) {

    if ($updateslide1type == 'image/gif' || $updateslide1type == 'image/jpg' || $updateslide1type == 'image/jpeg' && $updateslide1size > 0 && $updateslide1size < 2000000){

    move_uploaded_file($updateslide1temp,"../img/$updateslide1");

    $query = "UPDATE adminindex SET maintext='$updatemaintext', titletext='$updatetitletext', slidetitle1='$updateslidetitle1', slidetitle2='$updateslidetitle2', slidetitle3='$updateslidetitle3', slidetext1='$updateslidetext1', slidetext2='$updateslidetext2', slidetext3='$updateslidetext3', slide1='$updateslide1' WHERE id = '$updateid'";
    }       

        else{

            echo "<p>file needs to be a jpg/gif or file size too big.</p>";
            die();  
    }
    }else{ 


    $query = "UPDATE adminstore SET maintext='$updatemaintext', titletext='$updatetitletext', slidetitle1='$updateslidetitle1', slidetitle2='$updateslidetitle2', slidetitle3='$updateslidetitle3', slidetext1='$updateslidetext1', slidetext2='$updateslidetext2', slidetext3='$updateslidetext3' WHERE id = '$updateid'";

}

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (!empty($updateslide2)) {

    if ($updateslide2type == 'image/gif' || $updateslide2type == 'image/jpg' || $updateslide2type == 'image/jpeg' && $updateslide2size > 0 && $updateslide2size < 2000000){

    move_uploaded_file($updateslide2temp,"../img/$updateslide2");

    $query = "UPDATE adminindex SET maintext='$updatemaintext', titletext='$updatetitletext', slidetitle1='$updateslidetitle1', slidetitle2='$updateslidetitle2', slidetitle3='$updateslidetitle3', slidetext1='$updateslidetext1', slidetext2='$updateslidetext2', slidetext3='$updateslidetext3', slide2='$updateslide2' WHERE id = '$updateid'";
    }       

        else{

            echo "<p>file needs to be a jpg/gif or file size too big.</p>";
            die();  
    }
    }else{ 


    $query = "UPDATE adminindex SET maintext='$updatemaintext', titletext='$updatetitletext', slidetitle1='$updateslidetitle1', slidetitle2='$updateslidetitle2', slidetitle3='$updateslidetitle3', slidetext1='$updateslidetext1', slidetext2='$updateslidetext2', slidetext3='$updateslidetext3' WHERE id = '$updateid'";

}

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (!empty($updateslide3)) {

    if ($updateslide3type == 'image/gif' || $updateslide3type == 'image/jpg' || $updateslide3type == 'image/jpeg' && $updateslide3size > 0 && $updateslide3size < 2000000){

    move_uploaded_file($updateslide3temp,"../img/$updateslide3");

    $query = "UPDATE adminindex SET maintext='$updatemaintext', titletext='$updatetitletext', slidetitle1='$updateslidetitle1', slidetitle2='$updateslidetitle2', slidetitle3='$updateslidetitle3', slidetext1='$updateslidetext1', slidetext2='$updateslidetext2', slidetext3='$updateslidetext3', slide3='$updateslide3' WHERE id = '$updateid'";
    }       

        else{

            echo "<p>file needs to be a jpg/gif or file size too big.</p>";
            die();  
    }
    }else{ 


    $query = "UPDATE adminindex SET maintext='$updatemaintext', titletext='$updatetitletext', slidetitle1='$updateslidetitle1', slidetitle2='$updateslidetitle2', slidetitle3='$updateslidetitle3', slidetext1='$updateslidetext1', slidetext2='$updateslidetext2', slidetext3='$updateslidetext3' WHERE id = '$updateid'";

}

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Please check all your queries, some have field named `titletext` and in that table its not available.

Comment: Ok I feel incredibly stupid now, just saw what I did wrong. I was attempting to update a table named adminstore when it should've been adminindex.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement is attempting to update a table named `adminidex` and set a column named `titletext`, but apparently that column does not exist. Check your databases structure/schema to find the issue, maybe your missing an underscore or something.